# Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial getHeroes() function

Tags: angular

I have a question regarding the getHeroes() functiion in the Heroes tutorial for Angular:

```
getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
```

can somebody explain to me what the syntax "`heroes => this.heroes = heroes`" is doing? I'm coming from java and python and have never seen such an expression

the same goes for this:

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

what is `[class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"` doing?

Comment: 1. Learn TypeScript/ES6 syntax, that's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). 2. Learn Angular [template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), it's setting a class.

Comment: heroes => this.heroes = heroes is an arrow function in ES6 used inside subscription and which is equal to function (heroes) { this.heroes = heroes }... What it does is it will get the data heroes and assign it to this.heroes...you can find out more about it in https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#subscribe-in-heroescomponent and https://javascript.info/function-expressions-arrows

Answer (score 2):

## Arrow functions

```
heroes => this.heroes = heroes
```

The snippet above is roughly (not completely, especially because it contains a `this`, but serves as a good explanation) the same as the following.

```
function (heroes) { this.heroes = heroes }
```

The arrow syntax was introduced in EcmaScript 2015.

In JavaScript (just as in Python), functions are first-class citizens of the language, meaning they can be passed around just like any other constants or variables.

In this case, you're passing a function to the `subscribe` method of an Observable instance. This method accepts a function that will be executed once the event of getting heroes is observed. It will be passed the payload of that event, in this case `heroes`, and assign it to the class property of the same name (`this.heroes`).

You should [read more about **arrow functions** on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

## Angular template language

```
[class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
```

This is a specific thing to Angular template language. Templates are written in files with a common extension `.html`, but they are in fact not HTML (as you can see from that snippet).

`[class.foo]` expects an expression on the right hand side. If that expression results in a truthy value, class `foo` will be assigned to the element the directive is applied to. It's similar to saying the following.

```
if (hero === selectedHero)
  element.classList.add('foo')
else
  element.classList.remove('foo')
```

Of course, the main difference is that Angular generates this code in an optimized way so that it's evaluated every time `hero` or `selectedHero` changes, so you do not have to worry about manipulating the DOM on your own (which is the basic idea behind Angular anyway).